# windows 10 VPN connection fail

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

I'm having a problem connecting to VPN on my Windows 10 (with Ethernet).

VPN fail description:

> Can't connect to [my VPN]
>
> The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels
>   failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is
>   attempting to use an L2TP/IPsec tunnel, the security parameters
>   required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured properly.

I try ping to the server IP and successful: [my cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNwzS.png)

What confuse me is that the connection is good for half a year but fail recently, and the same configuration works fine on my OS X of laptop.

How could I solve it?

Comment: Has the VPN been working previously on the same Windows installation? Or have you recently updated to Windows 10?

Comment: @user1751825 It works previously for the same Windows. I don't remember if there is any update installation... If some update is installed, could I just reset some certain configuration of the network?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue with Cisco AnyConnect VPN client with Windows 10 OS.
It was typically after updating Windows 8.1 by Windows 10.

But if I install Clean Windows 10 then no issue.
If possible please update VPN Client.